# get the table data based on another table id

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables

table1

```
table1_ID     name    address
1             name1   bangalore
2             name2   chennai
3             name3   mumbai
```

table2

```
table2_ID     age     hobbies
1             20      reading
2             25      cricket 
3             22      indoor games
```

table3_mapping

```
table1_ID    table2_ID
1              2
2             2
3             1
```

now, how should I get the data from table2 based on table1_ID where,table1_ID->table2_ID......if I select name1 then i should get age and hobbies  of that name.  Hope you understood the problem.Thanks,,

Comment: Hint: `join` ... by the way, have you tried something yourself yet?  To get help on SO, you need to show some effort.

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: select t1.*,t2.* from table t3 join t1 on  t1.ID=t3.table1_ID  join t2 on  t2.ID=t3.table2_ID

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d1c18/2/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple use `join`

```
select t1.*,t2.* from t3 
join t1 on t1.ID=t3.table1_ID 
join t2 on t2.ID=t3.table2_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from table1 t1
join table3 t3 on t3.table1_id = t1.table1_id
join table2 t2 on t2.table2_id = t3.table2_id
```